# what is the right way to reduce multiple update statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables out of which one column/field is same in both tables, I need to update the Table A with data from table B.
Here table A.x value needs to be taken and compared with B.w and equivalant B.z value needs to be updated in A.x. x value differs from x1,x2 etc.. so each value needs to be taken and compared with w in Table B and equivalent z value need to be updated in x,x1,x2 etc in Table A.

```
Table A  (columns j, x, x1,x2,x3..x20 and so on)
---------

j x x1 x2 ..x20 and y y1 y2 .. y20




Table B (columns w and z)
--------
w   z



UPDATE TableA a SET a.x = (SELECT b.w
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE a.x = b.z)
WHERE a.j='somevalue';
```

If I write this way I need to write 40 update statement, is there any easy way to do these updates.

And the subquery might return multiple rows and I need to refine that too.

Thanks,
Ashraf

Comment: Are you saying that you have a whole bunch of columns that need to be the same in tables A and B?

Comment: bunch of columns in tableA needs to be compared in reference table table B. So here im comparing A.x with B.w and then taking the reference value B.z and updating it back in A.x.. So here A.x, A.x1..A.x20 needs to be compared and updated back into the table with reference values in Table B

Comment: On first glance this looks like a horrible database design. It seems x1, x2, ... had better be rows than columns. Anyway, how would the update for x1, x2, etc. look like. *Exactly* the same as for x, so I just replace x with x1, etc.?

Comment: And please show which record to pick in case of multiple rows matching, as you mention in your last sentence.

Comment: Something like: `set (x,y,z) = (select b.x, b.y, b.z from ....);`

Comment: these or sort of medical codes that come into x,x1..x20 for a claim.. so for a single claim there are sometimes 5 codes filled in x,x1,x2,x3,x4 or sometimes even 20 codes x,x1..x20..     so in Table B i have only 2 columns with 32,000 rows in it.. so it would based on condition a.x = b.z always ......`SET a.x = (SELECT b.w
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE a.x = b.z)` something like that but i need to check the value and assign back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a.x has another value as a.x1 and a.x2, etc. you need a subquery per value of course, because it is different b records you want to find.

```
UPDATE TableA a 
SET a.x = (SELECT b.w FROM TableB b WHERE a.x = b.z)
  , a.x1 = (SELECT b.w FROM TableB b WHERE a.x1 = b.z)
  , a.x2 = (SELECT b.w FROM TableB b WHERE a.x2 = b.z)
  ...
WHERE a.j = 'somevalue';
```

You might want to consider changing your table design for tableA, so as to have rows holding the values rather than columns. That would make updates (and queries in general for that matter) much easier.